# Bot Framework Adpative Forms - Submit Action not working

Tags: botframework, skype, adaptive-cards

I am trying to create an Adaptive forms using c#. I have installed Microsoft.AdaptiveCards Nuget package with Version 0.5.1 and Bot Builder version is 3.14.1.1.

My card has rendered correctly in Skype channel. But on click of Submit button, Forms input data Json is not passing to the Bot framework Post Activity. Submit Type is "Action.Submit". But this is working in Web chat.

I am using the below code.

```
                    var Makedmessage = context.MakeMessage();
                    AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
                    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
                    attach.ContentType = AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard.ContentType;
                    card.Body = new List<CardElement>() { new TextBlock() { Text = "Present a form and submit it back to the originator" }, new TextInput() { Id = "firstName", Placeholder = "What is your first name?" }, new TextInput() { Id = "lastName", Placeholder = "What is your last name?" } };
                    card.Actions = new List<ActionBase>() { new SubmitAction() { Title = "Action.Submit" } };
                    attach.Content = card;
                    Makedmessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                    Makedmessage.Attachments.Add(attach);
                    await context.PostAsync(Makedmessage, CancellationToken.None);
```

Also attached the Screenshot. [image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive cards are still [under development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/resources/partners#in-development) for Skype channel. You will have to look for other alternative feature like [multi dialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-BasicMultiDialog) or [formflow](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleSandwichBot) by Bot Framework to get the details of the user.

Comment: Thanks Anita. But the Adaptive cards getting rendered in my bot fine. Only thing is the Action.Submit doesn't do anything.

Comment: Anita George is correct.  Adaptive Cards are not fully supported on Skype yet.  The card might render correctly, but the button does not yet function as expected.